Module "twine" not found when using Azure DevOps pipeline
I'm running a pipeline in Azure Devops which is supposed to publish a wheel using "twine". The pipeline uses a Windows based image.
The pipeline is based on the docs from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pypi?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publish-python-packages-to-an-azure-artifacts-feed.
I tried with and without virtual environment and calling twine directly but also using python -m. Also tested using python3 instead of python, but no luck.
I always end up with the error C:\__t\Python\3.9.13\x64\python.exe: No module named twine 
Below the steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '3.x'
          disableDownloadFromRegistry: true
          addToPath: true
          architecture: 'x64'
        displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

      - script: |
          python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip setuptools wheel twine
          python -m venv myenv
          myenv/Scripts/activate
        displayName: 'Install Python Prerequesites'

      - script: |
          python setup.py bdist_wheel
        displayName: 'Build wheel'

      - task: TwineAuthenticate@1
        inputs:
          artifactFeed: 'MyProject/MyFeed'
        displayName: 'Twine Authenticate'

      - script: |
          # Also tried python -m twine...
          twine upload --repository-url https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_packaging/myfeed/pypi/upload/ dist/*.whl
        displayName: 'Upload to feed'


You probably want python3 -m twine upload, since python -m is not necessarily the same as python3 -m 

Sorry, I forgot to mention: I tried python3 instead of just python and "python3" cannot even be found. Updating  my question.

you probably need to activate in each script which uses the pip modules and then perhaps also -m twine.. this could be a case where you don't want a venv

Realistically, it's probably just best to use python since python 3.x has already been added to your path from the "Use Python" task

According to this document, we should reference the variable $(PYPIRC_PATH) generated by the TwineAuthenticate@1 task to publish twine packages to an Azure Artifacts feed.
Here is a sample YAML pipeline running on the windows-latest Microsoft-hosted agent.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- stage: CI
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    strategy:
      matrix:
        Python309:
          python.version: '3.9'
        Python312:
          python.version: '3.12'
    steps:
    - task: replacetokens@6
      inputs:
        root: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        sources: 'setup.py'
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

    - script: |
        python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip setuptools wheel twine
        python -m venv myenv
        myenv/Scripts/activate
      displayName: 'Install Python Prerequesites'

    - script: |
        python setup.py bdist_wheel
      displayName: 'Build wheel'

    - task: TwineAuthenticate@1
      inputs:
        artifactFeed: '$(ProjectName)/ProjectScopeFeed-twine'
      displayName: 'Twine Authenticate'

    - script: |
        python --version
        twine --version
        twine upload -r ProjectScopeFeed-twine --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*.whl
      displayName: 'Upload to feed'
    
    - publish: $(PYPIRC_PATH)
      artifact: pypirc$(python.version)


In case the issue only affects your pipeline running on your self-hosted agents, you will need to double check if you have correctly configured your self-hosted agent to use this task UsePythonVersion@0, since,

Downloading python versions is not supported on self-hosted agents. You may only use pre-installed versions.

Besides, the variable $(PYPIRC_PATH) points to the .pypirc file that contains the token of the pipeline service account. Therefore, please also make the respective (according to your job authorization scope) or both pipeline service accounts have sufficient permissions to publish packages to the feed.

